# C# WPF Generate a Sequential int value and Save it on SQL Server

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, wpf, database

I have a situation that I need to generate a sequential int value and save it on database, but it's never can be duplicated. I'm new in C# WPF, and how can I do it? The generated value must be displayed in textbox.

Comment: [SEQUENCE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878091.aspx), Get value from DB `SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR Test.DecSeq;` -> present to user -> save to DB

Comment: `Identity` for sql server 2005 or 2008  and  `Identity` OR `Sequence` if you are working on sql server 2012 or later versions.

Comment: @M.Ali yeah, Identity must be set in database, but in C# how can I do for get a sequence value after click in new button and show it on textbox?

Comment: `SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR Test.DecSeq`

Comment: @lad2025 do you have some examples?

Comment: @coreid read my first comment, also refresh page

Comment: @lad2025, thanks for help me. It works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible scenario using [SEQUENCE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878091.aspx) SQL Server 2012+

1. Create SEQUENCE in DB `CREATE SEQUENCE dbo.Sequence_name START WITH 1    INCREMENT BY 1;`
2. Query from Application using `SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR dbo.Sequence_name;`
3. Remember in Application, show user
4. Use when INSERT back to DB

Comment: In my application after using query = `SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR dbo.Sequence_name` how to display it textbox?

Comment: `txtBox.Text = generatedId`?

Comment: I used it: `string query = "SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR dbo.Sequence_name";
                _cmd = new SqlCommand(query, _con);
                txtSequence.Text = query;
                _con.Close();` but the result is the following string: ´SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR dbo.Sequence_name` ???

Comment: Why do you set `txtSequence.Text = query`?, you need to set result from SqlCommand.

Comment: What do you mean? Please post a example for this.

Comment: like `_con.Open(); result = com.Execute...; cast if needed type ; _con.Close() txtSequence.Text = result`

Comment: doesn't work like this: `_con.Open();
                _cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR dbo.Sequence_name");
                int result = (int)_cmd.ExecuteScalar();
                _con.Close();
                txtSequence.Text = result.ToString();`

Comment: ExecuteScalar: Connection property can not be initialized

Comment: @coreid Have you ever queried database from C#??? SqlCommand does not has connection `_cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR dbo.Sequence_name", _pass_connection_here)`

Comment: yeah I am so sorry for this error. Just little doubt If the User click the cancel button and clear the form and click New button again how to continue the same number before you click cancel?

Comment: Better not to reuse it, get new value and create a gap. It is safer.

Comment: thanks for all. Your help was so great. Thanks for a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

### Identity SQL Server 2000 and later

you can have an Identity Column in a table to generate sequential numbers something like....

```
CREATE TABLE SequenceTable(ID INT IDENTITY(1,1))
DECLARE @NewID INT;

INSERT INTO SequenceTable
DEFAULT VALUES 
SELECT @NewID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();

-- Now you can use this value anywhere you like text box etc.
SELECT @NewID
```

### Sequence SQL Server 2012 and Later only

```
CREATE SEQUENCE dbo.IncreamentValue
    START WITH 1
    INCREMENT BY 1 ;
GO
```

To get a sequence value from it

```
SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR dbo.IncreamentValue
```